# Copyright dates using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i am using twitter's bootstrap and its glyphicon for the copyright mark on our page footer.
i would like to add the current year to it and i dont want to hardcode it.
i have tried to look around in the official documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) , but could not really find anything.
what is the best way to achieve this using bootstrap? or is bootstrap not really meant to be used for this and its a complete javascript thing? (i am JS nube)

Comment: please leave a comment if you downvote, it would help me ask better questions in the future.

Comment: you have to try something (code), and then ask a question here. this  is how it works here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a pure HTML site, then you can do something like the following:

HTML:

```
<footer id="pagefooter">
   <p id="copyright"></p>
</footer>
```

JavaScript:

```
function copyrightYear() {
   var d = new Date();
   var y = d.getFullYear();
   document.getElementById("copyright").innerHTML = 'Copyright &copy; ' + y + ' Your Name Here';
}

copyrightYear();
```

As was noted in the other answer, you really do not need Bootstrap's icon in order to get the copyright symbol. It is built into HTML with the `&copy;` code and will use the same typeface as the element that contains it, in this case a paragraph tag.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need custom font icon for something available already in your standard character set? ©©©©

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm

```
&copy; // ©
```

Current year could be added with JS or server-side code. For example in JS use:

```
new Date().getFullYear()
```